Functional Equation $f(f(x))=af(x)+bx$ in new condition
Let $ f(x) \in C(\mathbb{R}) $, where $ a < -2 $, $ a^2 + 4b > 0 $, and $ b < a + 1 $. If $ f(x) $ satisfies the functional equation $ f(f(x)) = a f(x) + b x $ for all $ x $, find the general solution for $ f(x) $.
Let $ f(x) \in C(\mathbb{R}) $, and let $ a, b $ be real numbers such that the two roots $ u, v $ of the equation $ t^2 - a t - b = 0 $ satisfy $ u = -1 $, $ v < 0 $, and $ v \neq -1 $. If $ f(x) $ satisfies the functional equation $ f(f(x)) = a f(x) + b x $ for all $ x $, prove that $ f(x) $ is a piecewise linear function, and find all solutions.
I know that in the first problem, $f(x)$ is a monotonically decreasing function and has a unique fixed point at $x=0$, such that $f(0)=0$. It is also established that $f(+\infty)=-\infty$ and $f(-\infty)=+\infty$. Meanwhile, by solving the characteristic equation $x^2-a x-b=0$, we obtain the solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$. The general solution for the $n$-th iterate of the function $f(x)$ is given by $f^n(x)=C_1 x_1^n+C_2 x_2^n$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are determined by $f^0(x)=x$ and $f^1(x)=f(x)$
I would like to know how to approach similar problems, including methods and ideas. For the second problem, I don't have much of an idea about how to proceed. Additionally, I have found other similar problems where $x_1=x_2 \neq$ certain values, and I need to determine the expression for $f(x)$.
Thank you very much!

crucial that $f$ is continuous

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4 b}\right)\cdot x$$
